# Am I using python's subprocess.call correctly?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to create a series of tar files from within Python code. As a practice I have a subdirectory - 'O', which contains the files I want to tar. When I try typing

```
tar -cf O.tar ./O
```

from the command line, things work. But, when I enter the Python interpreter and enter

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["tar","-cf O.tar ./O"])
```

I get the following error:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
```

Does this make sense? I tried

```
import os
os.listdir(".")
```

To make sure I could still see my "O" subdirectory from within the Python shell, and I can.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["tar","-cf", "O.tar", "./O"])
```

Answer (score -1):

it will work run:

```
import subprocess
import sys
proc = subprocess.Popen(["tar","-cf O.tar ./O"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```

if you can execute some other command or program use sys.executeable()

Comment: it is incorrect. Each argument should be a separate list item. Look at the accepted answer from 3 years ago.